# Group 'continuation' items in list. Is storing state in itertools groupby key function bad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, grouping, python-itertools

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a function that groups list items with `None` signaling *continuation* items like so:

```
>>> g([1, None, 1, 1, None, None, 1])
[[1, None], [1], [1, None, None], [1]]
```

My real data has much more complex items but I've simplified things to the core for this question.

This is my solution so far:

```
import itertools

# input
x = [1, None, 1, 1, None, None, 1]

# desired output from g(x)
y = [[1, None], [1], [1, None, None], [1]]


def f(x):
    if x is None:
        f.lastx = x
    else:
        if x != f.lastx:
            f.counter += 1
    return f.counter


def g(x):
    f.lastx = None
    f.counter = 0
    z = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(x, f)]
    return z


assert y == g(x)
```

This works but I know it's very ugly.

Is there a better (and more Pythonic) way to do this? E.g. without a stateful key function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.accumulate`:

```
>>> dat = [1, None, 1, 1, None, None, 1]
>>> it = iter(dat)
>>> acc = accumulate(x is not None for x in dat)
>>> [[next(it) for _ in g] for _, g in groupby(acc)]
[[1, None], [1], [1, None, None], [1]]
```

This works because the `accumulate` will give us increasing intlike values at the start of every new group:

```
>>> list(accumulate(x is not None for x in dat))
[True, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

---

If you want to be able to handle a stream, just `tee` the iterator.  The maximum increase in memory use is only of order the size of one group.

```
def cgroup(source):
    it, it2 = tee(iter(source), 2)
    acc = accumulate(x is not None for x in it)
    for _,g in groupby(acc):
        yield [next(it2) for _ in g]
```

This still gives

```
>>> list(cgroup([1, None, 1, 1, None, None, 1]))
[[1, None], [1], [1, None, None], [1]]
```

but will work even with infinite sources:

```
>>> stream = chain.from_iterable(repeat([1, 1, None]))
>>> list(islice(cgroup(stream), 10))
[[1], [1, None], [1], [1, None], [1], [1, None], [1], [1, None], [1], [1, None]]
```

Comment: Wow, that's some dense code. :) It took me a bit to understand how it works but I like it and can see how this approach is fairly flexible.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed something... this approach requires 2 passes over input data. If data is streamed (as it is in my bigger problem) then this approach doesn't work. :(

Comment: @BrianG: then you shouldn't have said you were grouping *list* items. ;-)  But it's easy to handle a stream as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect because it needs a third-party extension ([`iteration_utilities.split`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/split.html)) and some tinkering but it does produce the desired output:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import split, is_not_None

>>> lst = [1, None, 1, 1, None, None, 1]

>>> list(split(lst, is_not_None, keep_after=True))[1:]
[[1, None], [1], [1, None, None], [1]]
```

The first element needs to be discarded (thus the `[1:]`) with this approach because otherwise the result would start with an empty sublist.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this. I was thinking some type of split might be more appropriate than a groupby. If I was wanting to go fully functional and use more of this library it might make sense, but for now I'd rather not add a dependency for just this one function.